# variadic template of a specific type

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, variadic-templates

I want a variadic template that simply accepts unsigned integers.
However, I couldn't get the following to work.

```
struct Array
{
    template <typename... Sizes> // this works
    // template <unsigned... Sizes> -- this does not work (GCC 4.7.2)
    Array(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        // This causes narrowing conversion warning if signed int is supplied.
        unsigned args[] = { sizes... };
        // ...snipped...
    }
};

int main()
{
    Array arr(1, 1);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: In case you're wondering, I'm trying to use variadic template to replicate the following.

```
struct Array
{
    Array(unsigned size1) { ... }
    Array(unsigned size1, unsigned size2) { ... }
    Array(unsigned size1, unsigned size2, unsigned size3) { ... }
    // ...
    Array(unsigned size1, unsigned size2, ..., unsigned sizeN) { ... }
};
```

Comment: And this arr(1, 1) would be a two dimensional array? Or an array with initial values {1, 1}?

Comment: There's no syntax to take a variable number of arguments of the same type, unfortunately. :/

Comment: @OlafDietsche: 2D array.

Comment: @Xeo: I am looking to replicate manually expanded Array c'tor with overloaded number of unsigned arguments (I have it up to 10 before).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why you expected that to work. Clang tells me the error is `unknown type name 'Sizes'` in the declaration of the constructor. Which is to be expected, since `Sizes` isn't a type (or rather, a template pack of types), it's a template pack of values.

It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do here. If you pass integral values in as template parameters, what are the constructor parameters supposed to be?

---

**Update**: With your new code all you need is a `static_cast<unsigned>()`.

```
struct Array
{
    template <typename... Sizes> // this works
    Array(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        unsigned args[] = { static_cast<unsigned>(sizes)... };
        // ...snipped...
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of the narrowing conversion warning (from int to unsigned) without forcing the user of Array to specify `Array arr(1u, 1u)`.

Comment: @ZachSaw: The entire "thing" that has the `...` after it is duplicated for each argument in the template pack. It all feels slightly magical.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to accept *dynamic* arguments that must all be integers, you want an ordinary *typename* template, but check that all the types are (convertible to) unsigned integers:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Array
{
    template <typename ...Args>
    explicit Array(Args ...args,
        typename std::enable_if<all_int<Args...>::value>::type * = nullptr);

    // ...
};
```

Now you just need the trait:

```
template <typename...> struct all_int;

template <> struct all_int<> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T, typename ...Rest> struct all_int<T, Rest...>
: std::integral_constant<bool,
       std::is_convertible<T, unsigned int>::value && all_int<Rest>::value>
{ }
```

If you prefer to make the types strict, you can also use `is_same` instead of `is_convertible`.

Another option is to forgo variadic templates entirely and make your class list-initializable by accepting a single `std::initializer_list<unsigned int>`, which provides considerably better numeric safety (for instance, narrowing conversions are forbidden).

Comment: The problem with this is that it will error out if you pass an `int` type rather than convert it to `unsigned`.

Comment: List-initialization is what prevents narrowing conversions, this is not special to `std::initializer_list`. Also, OP basically wants `Array(unsigned... args)`. And it's not about them being able to convert to `unsigned`, it's about them already *being* `unsigned` so he doesn't get narrowing conversions in the list-initialization inside the ctor.

Comment: @Pubby: Isn't `int` convertible-to `unsigned int`? Maybe `is_constructible` is a better trait.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, but you can't take advantage of list initialisation without initialiser lists, non?

Comment: `struct X{ X(unsigned, unsigned){} }; X x{1,2}; // error` (well, atleast when GCC correctly implements narrowing conversions as errors...)

Comment: @Xeo: Right, I see. Though that doesn't help, because we won't have fixed constructor arguments in the present case and I was after lists with arbitrary many elements. Interesting, though.

Answer (score 5):

Look into [initializer list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/)

You could specify it like

```
struct Array
{
    Array(std::initializer_list<unsigned> sizes)
    {
        for (auto i = sizes.begin(); i != sizes.end(); ++i)
            ...
    }
}
```

Although, usage would change to

```
Array arr = {1, 1};
```

Comment: I'm trying not to break the existing code using `()`. Using `std::initializer_list` would need me to change it to `{}`.

Comment: @ZachSaw Too bad, you cannot change that. Anyway, I added the change in usage to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Backstroy

When trying to achieve more or less what the OP tried to do, I stumbled across this rather old question. I had implemented something similar to  @Kerrek SB 's solution, and was looking for a way to 'generalize' this behavior (by providing a predicate as templated struct which is evaluated for not having to re-implement the 'recursion' for different predicates). 
However while doing so, I realized that the new CPP20 Concepts feature solves this issue in a very elegant way, and hence want to share this solution. I hadn't considered concepts as solution, as I read somewhere that they cannot be declared in a recursive way (which, as I found out, is not a practical burden, because I can refer to a recursive type trait solution).

### Solution

In this solution I define a custom concept, because I consider most real-world use-cases to not be covered by concepts provided by the STL, which could  be used in this case. Simply replacing the 'typename' by the concept in use, the concept is applied to all of the provided template arguments.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> concept unsignedType = std::is_unsigned_v<T>; 

struct Array {
  template <unsignedType... Sizes> Array(Sizes... sizes) {
    unsigned args[] = {sizes...};
  }
};

int main() {
  unsigned k = 12;
  Array arr(k, 1u); 
  //Array arr(33);  // fails as 33 is not unsigned
}
```

### Compilation

I am using gcc-10, in previous versions concept features might not be available as this feature is experimental: 
g++-10.0 -std=c++2a file.cc