# Variadic template parameters of one specific type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

Why there is no specific type allowed in a variadic template pack?

```
template< typename T >
class Foo
{
public:
    template< typename... Values >
    void bar( Values... values )
    {
    }

    template< T... values >            <-- syntax error
    void bar( T... values )
    {
    }

    template< int... values >          <-- syntax error
    void bar( int... values )
    {
    }
};
```

Whats the rationale in *not* allowing this?
Are there proposals for this?

---

Note: alternatives would be

- `std::initializer_list< T >` without narrowing of types and the `{ }`-brace-syntax
- a (ugly) recursive trait that checks all types seperately: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636290/variadic-template-of-a-specific-type)

Answer (score 8):

It IS allowed, actually, you're just using it wrong. `T...` and `int...` are non-type parameter packs and their elements are values, so you can't use them as type specifiers (and you can't deduce them from a function call).

An example of correct usage:

```
template<int... Is>
struct IntPack {};

IntPack<1,2,3> p;
```

or

```
template< typename T >
struct Foo
{
    template< T... Ts>
    void bar()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f;
    f.bar<1,2,3>();
}
```

Another example would be [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).