# Variadic template function with equal argument types

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I would like to write a template function like so:

```
template <typename T>
void f( const T & ...args ) // <-- This doesn't work, unfortunately.
{
    std::array<T> arr = { args... };
    // and so forth.
}
```

Apparently, C++ does not allow that, because there needs to be a template parameter pack on the left-hand side of `...args` for this to work. What I want is a template function where all argument types are the same. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: If you know every argument type is the same: `template<class T,class...Ts>void f(T const& x, Ts const&...xs){array<T,1+sizeof...(Ts)> arr={x,xs...};}`

Comment: is this similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773216/variadic-template-parameters-of-one-specific-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    template <typename ... T>
    void f(const T & ... args)
    {
        std::array<typename std::common_type<T...>::type,
                   sizeof...(T)> arr = {args...};
    }
```

or from [`std::experimental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array)

```
   template <typename ... T>
   void f(const T & ... args)
   {
        auto arr = std::experimental::make_array<void>(args...);
   }
```

The void makes the return type be the `common_type` of the input parameters, else you can specify what type you want explicitly if you know it.

Comment: You can omit the `<void>` for the default case

Comment: @melak47 Fair enough, I had just googled this function on a whim and otherwise never knew about it.  I'll keep it there so that people see that they can put whatever they want instead of `void`, but otherwise you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto f(const T& t, const Ts&... ts)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::tuple<T, Ts...>
                                          , std::tuple<Ts..., T>
                              >::value>::type
{
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57a9ca85bf5892c4)

Comment: I'm not sure the user was looking for a way to error if the parameters weren't all the same, but this is an interesting way to do that.

Comment: @GuyGreer *"What I want is a template function where all argument types are the same"*

Comment: I guess I didn't interpret that to mean he wanted to error if it wasn't.  I thought he was looking for a shorthand for when that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add one more solution to the ones already proposed.
You can also use an `initializer_list` to do that.
It follows a working example:

```
#include<initializer_list>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

template<class T>
void fn(std::initializer_list<T> l) {
    std::vector<T> v(l);
    // so on
}

int main() {
    fn<std::string>({ "foo", " bar" });
    return 0;
}
```